# Add check to a view on Android

Tags: java, android, view, listviewitem, multichoiceitems

Hello friends a question like I can add the following view to a view inside a gridview.
I am working on the selection of photos but I would like to be able to create a view
Like the following, but I have no idea how to add the check in the photo
Does anyone know how I can start on that?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You already did great.
Just follow this steps.

1. Initially, Hide the checkbox
2. Detect when user click the Grid cell, and make check visible
3. If user click again, Hide the Check

Comment: But for this implementation do you have to use some xml file?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a foreground drawable.

xml :

`android:foreground="@drawable/check_bg"`

java code :

`mImageView.setForeground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.check_bg));`